# Tidymodels - using a PCA output in a XGBoost Classification model

Tags: r, pca, xgboost, modeling, tidymodels

I am trying to run a classification model using XGBoost within a Tidymodels framework. I have been able to run the model already and the results are OK. As part of the refinement process I am trying to use PCA to return better results. I have engineered some features and the result is the following df

```
A tibble: 6 x 32
  ID    LIMIT_BAL   SEX EDUCATION MARRIAGE   AGE PAY_0 PAY_2 PAY_3 PAY_4 PAY_5 PAY_6
  <fct>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 3         90000     2         3        3     3     1     1     1     1     1     1
2 4         50000     2         3        2     4     1     1     1     1     1     1
3 6         50000     1         2        3     4     1     1     1     1     1     1
4 8        100000     2         3        3     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
5 10        20000     1         4        3     4     1     1     1     1     1     1
6 11       200000     2         4        3     3     1     1     2     1     1     1
# … with 20 more variables: BILL_AMT1 <dbl>, BILL_AMT2 <dbl>, BILL_AMT3 <dbl>,
#   BILL_AMT4 <dbl>, BILL_AMT5 <dbl>, BILL_AMT6 <dbl>, PAY_AMT1 <chr>, PAY_AMT2 <chr>,
#   PAY_AMT3 <chr>, PAY_AMT4 <chr>, PAY_AMT5 <chr>, PAY_AMT6 <chr>, default <fct>,
#   PAY_AMT <dbl>, lim_bal1 <dbl>, lim_bal2 <dbl>, lim_bal3 <dbl>, lim_bal4 <dbl>,
#   lim_bal5 <dbl>, lim_bal6 <dbl>
```

This training set is then used in the following recipe:

```
mas_rec <- recipe(default ~ ., data = cr_tr) %>% 
  step_select(-c(PAY_AMT1, PAY_AMT2, PAY_AMT3, PAY_AMT4, PAY_AMT5, PAY_AMT6, ID)) %>% 
  step_impute_bag(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_pca(all_predictors())
```

This recipe can be prepared as per the code below:

```
tic()
mod1_prep <- mas_rec %>% 
  check_missing(all_predictors()) %>% 
  prep()
mod1_prep 
toc()
juice(mod1_prep)
summary(mod1_prep) %>% arrange(role)
```

The output is as per below:

```
> juice(mod1_prep)
# A tibble: 16,168 x 6
   default    PC1    PC2    PC3    PC4    PC5
   <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 N       -0.971 -0.270 -0.999  0.803 -0.901
 2 N       -0.222 -0.141 -0.908 -0.726 -0.771
 3 N       -0.213 -0.170 -0.944  0.881 -0.102
 4 N       -1.77  -0.523 -0.547  1.39  -0.569
 5 N       -1.69  -0.468 -0.345 -0.138 -1.46 
 6 N       -1.25  -0.293  0.133  0.224 -1.19 
 7 N       -1.05  -0.164  0.510 -0.189  1.91 
 8 N       -0.963 -0.171 -1.22  -0.337  2.18 
 9 N        0.780  0.130 -1.12   1.48   0.633
10 N       -1.63  -0.512 -0.531  1.77   0.372
# … with 16,158 more rows

> summary(mod1_prep) %>% arrange(role)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  variable type    role      source  
  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   
1 default  nominal outcome   original
2 PC1      numeric predictor derived 
3 PC2      numeric predictor derived 
4 PC3      numeric predictor derived 
5 PC4      numeric predictor derived 
6 PC5      numeric predictor derived
```

The model is as below:

```
cr_boost <- boost_tree(
  mtry = tune(),
  trees = 1000,
  min_n = tune(),
  tree_depth = tune(),
  learn_rate = tune(),
  loss_reduction = tune(),
  sample_size = tune()) %>% 
  set_engine("xgboost") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")
```

The rest of the process is as per below:

```
# Parallel Processing ----
cores <- detectCores() -1
registerDoParallel(cores = cores)

# Re-sampling with cross validation ----
tree_folds <- vfold_cv(cr_tr)
control <- control_grid(save_pred = TRUE)

# 3. Create a Work-flow ----
cr_wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(mod1_prep) %>% 
  add_model(cr_boost) 
cr_wf

# Set the Grid Space for the model ----
xg_boost_grid <- grid_latin_hypercube(
  tree_depth(),
  min_n(),
  loss_reduction(),
  sample_size = sample_prop(),
  finalize(mtry(), cr_tr),
  learn_rate(),
  size = 30)
```

The tune process is as below:

```
xg_boost_tnd <- tune_grid(
  cr_wf,
  resamples = tree_folds,
  grid = xg_boost_grid,
  control = control)
print("It's done, check the results below")
xg_boost_tnd
toc()
```

When I run this the following message appears:

```
Warning message:
This tuning result has notes. Example notes on model fitting include:
preprocessor 1/1: Error in svd(x, nu = 0, nv = k): a dimension is zero
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without a reprex it can be hard to diagnose completely. One thing that could have happened is that some of the variables inside the cross-validation folds have become constant/zero variance which pca doesn't like. Try putting an `step_zv(all_predictors())` before `step_pca()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately it still doesn't work and reproduces the same error.  I am almost certain the solution is in/ around the zero variance issue but unfortunately I am out of ideas on how to remedy the sitn. I'll keep thinking and researching to get the result. thx

Comment: I reflexively add `step_zv()` before normalizing the data.

Comment: I have the same error, and none of my variables have 0 variance. I checked before plugging into the recipe. Out of ideas...